# Check if string exists in JSON array in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

Trying to return rows that the JSON value contains a certain value.

```
Table Structure
ID     Mapping
1      {"DepartmentID":"Finishing","ShipToIDs":[],"ItemIDs":[]}
2      {"DepartmentID":"Finishing","ShipToIDs":["100"],"ItemIDs":["300-VLR1022A"]}
3      {"DepartmentID":"Finishing","ShipToIDs":["100"],"ItemIDs":[]}
```

For example, passing in ShipToIDs = 100 would return rows 2-3 and passing in ItemID = 300-VLR1022A would return row 2.

Comment: Which is your RDBMS? Please tag it.

Comment: If you find yourself needing to look inside JSON fields in SQL, it's probably time to define relational schema around those fields and populate at insert/update time. Not _every_ json attribute, mind you; just the ones you'll need to search. Otherwise, not only do you have to parse and look inside the json for the rows you need, but you'll also have to parse the json of **every record in the table.** Additionally, if you have extracted this data at insert/update time you can also have indexes around those fields. _**Without exaggeration, it can be 1000 times faster.**_

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah...its a very small table, and we dont know what is going to be stored in the mapping yet, and it just makes sense for now to store it in this way,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 SQL Server has built in JSON querying functionality.

Comment: I tried that but couldnt find like, a contains or where withing the query. you ha to reference each element individually.

Comment: If this isn't going to be modelled relationally, why even put it in a database? Just use one of the many data lake technologies around to store and query a file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need SQL Server 2016 or later to make use of this, but it seems that you are looking for [JSON_QUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql), e.g.:

```sql
/*
 * Data setup...
 */
create table dbo.Example (
  ID int,
  Mapping nvarchar(max)
);

insert dbo.Example (ID, Mapping) values
  (1, N'{"DepartmentID":"Finishing","ShipToIDs":[],"ItemIDs":[]}'),
  (2, N'{"DepartmentID":"Finishing","ShipToIDs":["100"],"ItemIDs":["300-VLR1022A"]}'),
  (3, N'{"DepartmentID":"Finishing","ShipToIDs":["100"],"ItemIDs":[]}');

/*
 * JSON_QUERY examples...
 */
select ID
from dbo.Example
cross apply openjson(Mapping, '$.ShipToIDs') ShipToID
where ShipToID.Value = '100';

select ID
from dbo.Example
cross apply openjson(Mapping, '$.ItemIDs') ItemID
where ItemID.Value = '300-VLR1022A';
```

Which yields the results:

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

and:

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2017+, you can use `OPENJSON` with a dynamic path

```sql
DECLARE @path nvarchar(max) = N'$.ShipToIDs';
DECLARE @value nvarchar(max) = N'100';

SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON(t.Mapping, @path) j
    WHERE j.value = @value);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=08ee3e4bb36185531de897db38223272)